# JpaRepository is null

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, vaadin

I am trying to connect database to my vaadin-app, using javaConfig. But my Layout does not get a JpaRepository injected.

[image]

HotelCategoryServiceImpl.java

```
package com.gptravel.service.category;


import com.gptravel.dao.HotelCategoryRepository;
import com.gptravel.entity.HotelCategory;
import com.gptravel.service.hotel.HotelServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;    

@Service("hotelCategoryService")
@Transactional
public class HotelCategoryServiceImpl implements HotelCategoryService {
private static final Logger LOGGER = 
Logger.getLogger(HotelServiceImpl.class.getName());

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Autowired
private HotelCategoryRepository hotelCategoryRepo;

@Override
public HotelCategory create(HotelCategory hotelCategory) {
    HotelCategory savehotelCategory = 
 hotelCategoryRepo.saveAndFlush(hotelCategory);
    return savehotelCategory;
}

@Override
public void delete(long id) {
    hotelCategoryRepo.delete(id);

}

@Override
public HotelCategory getById(long id) {
    return hotelCategoryRepo.findOne(id);
}

@Override
public HotelCategory update(HotelCategory hotelCategory) {
    return hotelCategoryRepo.saveAndFlush(hotelCategory);
}

//get all categories
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public  List<HotelCategory> findAll() {
    return hotelCategoryRepo.findAll();
}
}
```

HotelCategoryService.java

```
package com.gptravel.service.category;


import com.gptravel.entity.HotelCategory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service("hotelCategoryService")
public interface HotelCategoryService {

HotelCategory create(HotelCategory hotelCategory);
void delete(long id);
HotelCategory getById(long id);
HotelCategory update(HotelCategory hotelCategory);
List<HotelCategory> findAll();
}
```

Repository:

```
import com.gptravel.entity.HotelCategory;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface HotelCategoryRepository extends 
JpaRepository<HotelCategory, Long> {

List<HotelCategory> findAllBy(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Jpa Config.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.gptravel")
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.gptravel.dao")
public class HibernateConfig {

@Resource
private Environment environment;

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() throws NamingException {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new 
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new 
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.gptravel.entity");
    factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());

    factoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass
    (HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
    factoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties());
    factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("demo_hotels");
    factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factoryBean.getObject();
}

private Properties jpaProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", 
environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", 
environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", 
environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    return properties;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws 
NamingException {
    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
    return txManager;
}

@Bean
public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
    SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
    liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:db/db.changelog.xml");
    liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource());
    return liquibase;
}
}
```

My app have simple test connect to database, which ends successfully
TestJpaConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.gptravel")
public class TestDataBaseConfig {

private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo_hotels";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "demo";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "demo";

private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "true";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "com.gptravel.entity";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO = "update";

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);

    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProp());

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());

    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClassName(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER);
    dataSource.setUrl(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL);
    dataSource.setUsername(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME);
    dataSource.setPassword(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD);

    return dataSource;
}

private Properties hibernateProp() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT);
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL);
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO);
    return properties;
}

}
```

TestClass.java

```
@DirtiesContext
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestDataBaseConfig.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class HotelServiceImplTest {
@Resource
private EntityManagerFactory emf;
protected EntityManager em;

@Resource
private HotelRepository hotelCategoryService;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
em = emf.createEntityManager();
}

@Test
public void testSaveHotelCategory() throws Exception {
hotelCategoryService.findAll();
List<Hotel> testList = hotelCategoryService.findAll();
System.out.println("Size - " + testList.size());


}

}
```

What could be the problem?

**UPDATE #1**

I added annotation like `@Service`, `@Component` but app still doesn't work.

Link to my repo: [VaadinJPAHotelApp](https://bitbucket.org/dmitriu_p/gptravel)

Comment: Looking at the attached image, it looks like `HotelForm` class is not a spring bean. Hence the fields are not Autowired. Do you have `@Component` or `@Service` annotations on this class ?

Comment: suppose the `HotelCategoryService` interface do not need the `@Service("hotelCategoryService")` declaration.

Comment: Added annotations, but did not help

Comment: Turn on logging for org.springframework and post your startup log, so we can see what beans are being created and how they are being autowired.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to change this in HotelCategoryServiceImpl class.

```
@Service("HotelCategoryServiceImpl")
@Transactional
public class HotelCategoryServiceImpl implements HotelCategoryService {
private static final Logger LOGGER =
```

Go through following code for reference. 
[HotelCategoryRestCall](https://github.com/dornala/HotelStackoverflow)

- Please go through annotations carefully.

Comment: Thank you for best example, but app like spring mvc work with jpaRepository for me.
Whereas my vaadin app persistently refuses to work :(

I added link to my repo, maybe it help me

Answer (score 0):

1. it is not that `findAll` returns `null`, but your `HotelCategoryService` is `null`.
2. You have an instance of `HotelForm`, but you don't get any Spring related exceptions, although the `@Autowired` fields aren't autowired. This means this instance does not get created by Spring but by something else (Vaadin maybe?).

Instances that are supposed to get dependencies injected by Spring have to get created by Spring. So check how you are creating your instances. Just slapping Spring annotations on it won't be sufficient, since obviously right now you are not asking Spring to create an instance for you, but something else, which probably won't give a damn about Spring annotations.

Also maybe this [tutorial which shows how to integrate Vaadin with Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/crud-with-vaadin/) is of some help

And please: *Do not use images to communicate code in the future*